# de novo gene synthesis vs cDNA library creation from plant RNA: Pros & Cons

Tags: molecular-biology, rna, cloning, cdna

What are the relative pros & cons of the following two approaches when one wants to insert a known, sequenced plant gene into a target host organism:

1. de novo gene synthesis vs
2. plant matter extracted RNA converted to a cDNA library

Specifically my gene of interest is approx. 2000 base pairs so de novo gene synthesis cost works to about $350. (please correct my estimate if I'm wrong)

While this isn't cheap, collecting plant samples, cryopreservation, digestion, extraction etc. aren't easy either.

Any other considerations when / why one may favor one approach over the other?

Comment: Isn't "collecting plant samples, cryopreservation, digestion, extraction etc." also expensive? Think about cost and time. How long would it take to isolate the DNA vs synthesize it?